# shared_ptr assignment notation implicit conversion

Tags: c++, c++11, shared-ptr, explicit

considering following code  , Why I can’t use the
assignment notation here , Why that is considered to be an implicit conversion.

```
shared_ptr<string> pNico = new string("nico"); // ERROR implicit conversion
shared_ptr<string> pNico{new string("nico")};   // OK
```

Comment: Perhaps construction from a raw pointer is made explicit for `shared_ptr` so that `foo(&obj);` won't accidentally take ownership of `obj`

Comment: The assignment operator is not overloaded for `T*`, only for other smart pointers

Comment: @xvan it's not an assignment, but construction

Comment: @xvan yes its construction

Comment: There's also `make_shared`.

Comment: I'm guessing it's VC++ and it's a bug?

Comment: @DavidHaim it's not a bug

Comment: @sleeptightpupper Question isn't here that we use make_shared , iknow that make_shared way of creation is faster and safer because it uses one instead of two allocations: one for the
object and one for the shared data the shared pointer uses to control the object

Comment: @DavidHaim , NO there is no bug

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki , i find your Answer correct , could you please explain it in details

Comment: @Adib the syntax `T x = y;` is called *copy-initialization*, as opposed to `T x(y);` which is *direct-initialization*. Copy-initialization applies not only to `T x = y;`, but also for passing arguments to a function, `f(y);` with e.g. `void f(T x) {}`. the `explicit` specifier prevents implicit conversions that could happen in copy-initialization. I believe it was made intentionally for `shared_ptr`, for the reason I mentioned

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The constructor is explicit to prevent somebody from doing something like this:

```
void foo(std::shared_ptr<std::string> s) { }

int main()
{
   std::string s;
   foo(&s);
}
```

If it was implicit, the `shared_ptr` could take ownership of a stack allocated variable and try to delete it..which wouldn't make sense.

Answer (score 2):

Check the [constructors declarations](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/shared_ptr):

ie

```
template< class Y >
explicit shared_ptr( Y* ptr );
```

the [`explicit`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/explicit) keyword prevents the copy initialization.

Only [Converting constructors](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/converting_constructor) can be used on copy initialization.